# Getting specific values from a range of time in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TngnA.png)

Hi. My problem is: Given a range of 1 minute in that DataFrame, ask and bid will change, sometimes no but sometimes more often. I need to get the first value, max, min and last and create a new dataframe of 1 minute interval.
If there is a change in bid and ask, I will get the mean. Let me show what did i do:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y.%m.%d', errors='coerce')  
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f', errors='coerce')  
days = df['Date'].unique()  
hour = np.arange(0,24)  
minute = np.arange(0,60)  
open_list = []
for d in days:
  for h in hour:
    for m in minute:
      open = 0
      l = len(df[(df['Date'] == d) & (df['Time'].dt.hour == h) & (df['Time'].dt.minute == m)][['Bid','Ask']])
      if l != 0:
        open = df[(df['Date'] == d) & (df['Time'].dt.hour == h) & (df['Time'].dt.minute == m)][['Bid','Ask']].iloc[0].values
      else:
        continue
      if len(open) == 2:
        open_list.append((open.sum() / 2))
      else:
        open_list.append(open)
```

As you can see, it would take a life time for me. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Please post `df.head(5).to_dict()` so we can easily help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I haven't your data I can try to explain the method I'd use:

- Create a column with `df["dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])`
- Then I'd use [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html)`('1Min').agg(['mean','min', 'max', 'last'])`

Comment: I will try. Data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YZkvneAEyfe8er1eLdliNVXQqz678u_h/view?usp=sharing